# loading epoch time stored in file and plotting on matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, epoch

I have a file which contains

```
1349542114842,2
1349542114872,4
1349542116037,1
1349542126680,5
1349542190738,3
1349542190775,4
```

where the first column is epoch time.

I am loading it into matlab using a

```
load('path to file')
```

as soon as i load it I can see that the first column is changing to display

```
1.349542114842000e+12
```

this would be very confusing for me as when I plot, my axis value is the epoch time which is quite skewed.
any ideas ?? ( the hack I can think of is to subtract e+3 while plotting but it does not solve my problem completely)

Comment: The values you're actually loading, are of order `1e13`, so there is nothing wrong with loading the data. Did you try plotting the values? What's the problem with that?

Comment: The way variables appear when displayed (e.g. when you type varname<enter>) is controlled by the display format.  Try typing "format long g" and then looking at your time stamp variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the first column indeed consists of non-negative integer values, you can cast it to [`uint64`](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/uint64.html) to get full precision:

```
format long % just for display purpose: 

% with double precision
a = [
    1349542114842,2
    1349542114872,4
    1349542116037,1
    1349542126680,5
    1349542190738,3
    1349542190775,4
    ];
```

This results in

```
>> a

a =

  1.0e+012 *

   1.349542114842000   0.000000000002000
   1.349542114872000   0.000000000004000
   1.349542116037000   0.000000000001000
   1.349542126680000   0.000000000005000
   1.349542190738000   0.000000000003000
   1.349542190775000   0.000000000004000
```

Now casting to uint64:

```
% now with unsigned integer 64 precision
a = uint64([
    1349542114842,2
    1349542114872,4
    1349542116037,1
    1349542126680,5
    1349542190738,3
    1349542190775,4
    ]);
```

This results in:

```
>> a

a =

        1349542114842                    2
        1349542114872                    4
        1349542116037                    1
        1349542126680                    5
        1349542190738                    3
        1349542190775                    4
```

Answer (score 2):

Your epochs look like [unix time stamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), accurate in milliseconds. You could convert these to `datenums`:

```
a = [
1349542114842,2
1349542114872,4
1349542116037,1
1349542126680,5
1349542190738,3
1349542190775,4
];

b = a(:,1)/1000/86400 + datenum(1970,1,1);
```

which you then use to make the plot. You can properly display them like so:

```
datetick('y', 'mmm dd, HH:MM:SS')
```

which results in this:

[image: nice y labels]

Alternatively, if you want them on the `x`-axis, you'll probably want to rotate the labels. You're best off using [this utility off the file exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27812-rotate-x-axis-tick-labels) for that, because doing it by hand is a **real pain** (and is something Matlab should start supporting natively IMHO).

Answer (score 1):

If the problem is that the plot's yaxis is not showing the full numbers (eg `1.35e12` instead of `1349542114840`, `1349542114870` etc) you can change the format using this tool: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36254-ticklabelformat

Example:

```
plot(1:10, (1:10) + 1e12);
ticklabelformat(gca,'y','%d')
```

Result:

[image]